Is it not possible to verify NFT collections with the set_and_verify_collection function in the current version?
Please understand that the meaning may not be conveyed properly due to the use of Google Translator.
To get straight to the point, we are trying to verify the collection set using the set_and_verify_collection function after NFT minting in the on-chain code (Rust).
Currently, minting is progressing normally, but the transaction process is failing due to the error "Collection Must Be a Unique Master Edition v2'" while processing set_and_verify_collection.

Error log

'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [2]',
'Program log: IX: Set and Verify Collection',
'Program log: Collection Must Be a Unique Master Edition v2',
'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 27034 of 39651 compute units',
'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: custom program error: 0x52',
As far as I know, if the NFT used as the collection ID is set to Master Edition v3, it is okay to request Master Edition v2, but I am embarrassed that this error keeps occurring.
I'm wondering if I'm using the set_and_verify_collection function incorrectly, or if the collection ID should be set to Master Edition v2, or if verification isn't done this way in the current version.
I searched Google, Bing, and other places about this error, but I couldn't find much information, so I'm posting my question here.
I'll attach my code below.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
NFT Minting Code (Rust)
use solana_program::{
account_info::{next_account_info, AccountInfo},
entrypoint,
entrypoint::ProgramResult,
msg,
program::{invoke, invoke_signed},
program_error::ProgramError,
pubkey::Pubkey,};

use mpl_token_metadata::{instruction::{create_master_edition_v3, create_metadata_accounts_v3, set_and_verify_collection}, state::Collection};
use mpl_token_metadata::state::Creator;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use spl_token::instruction::{initialize_mint, mint_to, initialize_account};
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct MetadataStruct {
pub name: String,
pub symbol: String,
pub uri: String,
pub seller_fee_basis_points: u16,
}
entrypoint!(process_instruction);
fn process_instruction(
program_id: &Pubkey,
accounts: &[AccountInfo],
input: &[u8]
) -> ProgramResult {
msg!("Start Program : {}", program_id);
let account_info_iter = &mut accounts.iter();
let payer_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; //수수료 지불자 계정
let mint_authority = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; //민팅 권한 계정
let update_authority = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; //업데이트 권한 계정
let mint_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; //민팅 계정
let token_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; //토큰 계정
let metadata_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; //메타데이터 계정
let master_edition_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; //마스터 에디션 계정
let system_program = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; //솔라나 시스템 프로그램 키
let rent_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; //솔라나 임대료 체크용 프로그램 키
let metadata_program = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; //메타플렉스 프로그램 키
let token_program = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; //토큰 프로그램 키
let client_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; //NFT 소유자 주소
let collection_mint = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; // 컬렉션 민트 주소
let collection_metadata = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; // 컬렉션 메타데이터 주소
let collection_master_edition_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; // 컬렉션 마스터 에디션 계정 주소

// Metadata 구조체 파싱
let metadata: MetadataStruct = serde_json::from_slice(input)
    .map_err(|_| ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData)?;


msg!("Initializing mint account");
let init_mint_ix = initialize_mint(
    &spl_token::id(),
    mint_account.key,
    mint_authority.key,
    Some(mint_authority.key),
    0,
)?;

invoke(
    &init_mint_ix,
    &[
        mint_account.clone(),
        rent_account.clone(),
        token_program.clone(),
    ]
)?;

msg!("Initializing token account");
let init_token_account_ix = initialize_account(
    &spl_token::id(),
    token_account.key,
    mint_account.key,
    client_account.key,
)?;

invoke(
    &init_token_account_ix,
    &[
        token_account.clone(),
        mint_account.clone(),
        client_account.clone(),
        rent_account.clone(),
        token_program.clone(),
    ],
)?;

msg!("Creating metadata account");
let creators = vec![
    Creator {
        address: *payer_account.key,
        verified: true,
        share: 100,
    },
];

// 컬렉션 설정
let collection = Some(Collection {
    verified: false,
    key: *collection_mint.key,
});

let create_metadata_ix = create_metadata_accounts_v3(
    *metadata_program.key,
    *metadata_account.key,
    *mint_account.key,
    *mint_authority.key,
    *payer_account.key,
    *update_authority.key,
    metadata.name,
    metadata.symbol,
    metadata.uri,
    Some(creators),
    metadata.seller_fee_basis_points,
    true,
    true,
    collection,
    None,
    None,
);

invoke_signed(
    &create_metadata_ix,
    &[
        metadata_account.clone(),
        mint_account.clone(),
        mint_authority.clone(),
        payer_account.clone(),
        update_authority.clone(),
        system_program.clone(),
        rent_account.clone(),
    ],
    &[],
)?;

msg!("Minting one token to token account");
let mint_to_ix = mint_to(
    &spl_token::id(),
    mint_account.key,
    token_account.key,
    mint_authority.key,
    &[],
    1,
)?;

invoke(
    &mint_to_ix,
    &[
        mint_account.clone(),
        token_account.clone(),
        mint_authority.clone(),
        token_program.clone(),
    ]
)?;

msg!("Creating master edition account");
let create_master_edition_ix = create_master_edition_v3(
    *metadata_program.key,
    *master_edition_account.key,
    *mint_account.key,
    *update_authority.key,
    *mint_authority.key,
    *metadata_account.key,
    *payer_account.key,
    Some(1),
);

invoke_signed(
    &create_master_edition_ix,
    &[
        master_edition_account.clone(),
        mint_account.clone(),
        update_authority.clone(),
        mint_authority.clone(),
        payer_account.clone(),
        metadata_account.clone(),
        token_program.clone(),
        system_program.clone(),
    ],
    &[],
)?;

msg!("Verifying collection");
let set_and_verify_collection_ix = set_and_verify_collection(
    *metadata_program.key,
    *metadata_account.key,
    *payer_account.key,
    *payer_account.key,
    *update_authority.key,
    *collection_mint.key,
    *collection_metadata.key,
    *collection_master_edition_account.key,
    None,
);

invoke_signed(
    &set_and_verify_collection_ix,
    &[
        metadata_account.clone(),
        payer_account.clone(),
        payer_account.clone(),
        update_authority.clone(),
        collection_mint.clone(),
        collection_metadata.clone(),
        collection_master_edition_account.clone(),
    ],
    &[],
)?;

msg!("NFT minted to payer's account successfully!");

Ok(())

}
NFT creation code for collection ID
use solana_program::{
account_info::{next_account_info, AccountInfo},
entrypoint,
entrypoint::ProgramResult,
msg,
program::{invoke, invoke_signed},
program_error::ProgramError,
pubkey::Pubkey,

};
use mpl_token_metadata::instruction::{create_master_edition_v3, create_metadata_accounts_v3};
use mpl_token_metadata::state::Creator;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use spl_token::instruction::{initialize_mint, mint_to, initialize_account};
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct MetadataStruct {
pub name: String,
pub symbol: String,
pub uri: String,
pub seller_fee_basis_points: u16,
}
entrypoint!(process_instruction);
fn process_instruction(
program_id: &Pubkey,
accounts: &[AccountInfo],
input: &[u8]
) -> ProgramResult {
msg!("Start Program : {}", program_id);
let account_info_iter = &mut accounts.iter();
let payer_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; //수수료 지불자 계정
let mint_authority = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; //민팅 권한 계정
let update_authority = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; //업데이트 권한 계정
let mint_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; //민팅 계정
let token_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; //토큰 계정
let metadata_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; //메타데이터 계정
let master_edition_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; //마스터 에디션 계정
let system_program = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; //솔라나 시스템 프로그램 키
let rent_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; //솔라나 임대료 체크용 프로그램 키
let metadata_program = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; //메타플렉스 프로그램 키
let token_program = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; //토큰 프로그램 키
let client_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; //NFT 소유자 주소

// Metadata 구조체 파싱
let metadata: MetadataStruct = serde_json::from_slice(input)
    .map_err(|_| ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData)?;


msg!("Initializing mint account");
let init_mint_ix = initialize_mint(
    &spl_token::id(),
    mint_account.key,
    mint_authority.key,
    Some(mint_authority.key),
    0,
)?;

invoke(
    &init_mint_ix,
    &[
        mint_account.clone(),
        rent_account.clone(),
        token_program.clone(),
    ]
)?;

msg!("Initializing token account");
let init_token_account_ix = initialize_account(
    &spl_token::id(),
    token_account.key,
    mint_account.key,
    client_account.key,
)?;

invoke(
    &init_token_account_ix,
    &[
        token_account.clone(),
        mint_account.clone(),
        client_account.clone(),
        rent_account.clone(),
        token_program.clone(),
    ],
)?;

msg!("Creating metadata account");
let creators = vec![
    Creator {
        address: *payer_account.key,
        verified: true,
        share: 100,
    },
];

let create_metadata_ix = create_metadata_accounts_v3(
    *metadata_program.key,
    *metadata_account.key,
    *mint_account.key,
    *mint_authority.key,
    *payer_account.key,
    *update_authority.key,
    metadata.name,
    metadata.symbol,
    metadata.uri,
    Some(creators),
    metadata.seller_fee_basis_points,
    true,
    true,
    None,
    None,
    None,
);

invoke_signed(
    &create_metadata_ix,
    &[
        metadata_account.clone(),
        mint_account.clone(),
        mint_authority.clone(),
        payer_account.clone(),
        update_authority.clone(),
        system_program.clone(),
        rent_account.clone(),
    ],
    &[],
)?;

msg!("Minting one token to token account");
let mint_to_ix = mint_to(
    &spl_token::id(),
    mint_account.key,
    token_account.key,
    mint_authority.key,
    &[],
    1,
)?;

invoke(
    &mint_to_ix,
    &[
        mint_account.clone(),
        token_account.clone(),
        mint_authority.clone(),
        token_program.clone(),
    ]
)?;

msg!("Creating master edition account");
let create_master_edition_ix = create_master_edition_v3(
    *metadata_program.key,
    *master_edition_account.key,
    *mint_account.key,
    *update_authority.key,
    *mint_authority.key,
    *metadata_account.key,
    *payer_account.key,
    Some(1),
);

invoke_signed(
    &create_master_edition_ix,
    &[
        master_edition_account.clone(),
        mint_account.clone(),
        update_authority.clone(),
        mint_authority.clone(),
        payer_account.clone(),
        metadata_account.clone(),
        token_program.clone(),
        system_program.clone(),
    ],
    &[],
)?;

msg!("NFT minted to payer's account successfully!");

Ok(())

}
